# For(a,b) function (or not)?

Tags: python

I met a line in python code:

```
onevariable for(a,b) in range(1,10)
```

Can you help me how it should be 'read'? Couldn't 'google' any example of 'for' with brackets. Very strange line

Comment: Did you try running it to see what happens?

Comment: `for(a,b) in range(1,10)` can't work. But you're probably refering to list comprehensions.

Comment: @jeanfrancoisefabre but it can't work in a list comp either?

Comment: @roganjosh you cannot unpack a&b from a range.

Comment: @jeanfrancoisefabre Exactly as I was thinking, so a list comp can't make it work. It's just broken code either way I guess.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You can if you replace the built-in `range`...

Comment: @StefanPochmann lol

Comment: @roganjosh you're not pinging me but you're pinging Jean-Francoise Fabre if this user exists (and is a girl :))

Answer (score 0):

It's just a [target list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements); [tuple assignment](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) is available just about everywhere variables are set, including in a comprehension.